# How to make line graph in unity3d app

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, linegraph

I want to make line graph in unity for iOS and android application. I found the sample library for iOS there is lot of library available,but there is no unity plugin for line graph. I think it is most complex to make graph in unity.Below there is link of line graph library which is available for iOS.I want to make line graph like that.

https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph

Comment: What about these? [Graph Master](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12637), [Graph Maker](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11782)

Comment: i used graph maker but it need to import NGUI Plugins that i don't want to import nGUI, I used vectrosity plugin which good for graph making, but i stuck in making curve line.

Comment: here is link of unity answer where i describe in details http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1012523/how-to-draw-graphline-graph-spline-graph-in-unity.html

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Maker](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11782) can create these Graphs in Unity on iOS and does not require any third party assets so long as you are using Unity 4.6+ (The Unity version at which Unity's UI system was introduced)